# Grant SELECT,INSERT,CREATE,DROP TABLE permissions for all tables in a schema of a DB to a LoginRole without making them owner of DB/Schema in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database named: **my_database** (owner login role: 'admin')
There are two schemas in the database: **my_schema_1** (owner login role: 'admin') and **my_schema_2** (owner login role: 'admin')

Each of these schemas have variable number of tables. What I mean by variable is that there's a Python script that runs every night to drop all tables in **my_schema_1** and create and fill new tables in **my_schema_1**.
I want my python script to use a different login role than 'admin' to do this job. Let's say the login role used by the Python Script to CREATE, DROP, COPY FROM/TO TABLE and INSERT INTO, SELECT FROM in the tables of **my_schema_1** is 'dev'.
How do I give the necessary permissions to 'dev' TO CREATE, DROP, INSERT, COPY, SELECT tables in **my_schema_1** of **my_database**, without making 'dev' the owner of database and/or schema.

I have tried this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema_1 TO dev;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, CREATE, DROP ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema_1 TO dev;
```

This failed badly because it doesn't let me do a GRANT on CREATE/DROP statements. How do I achieve that?

Even then, I tried:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema_1 TO dev;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema_1 TO dev;
```

And I kept getting this:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: permission denied for schema my_schema_1
```

Comment: what's your postgresql version?

Answer (score 0):

If your postgresql is >= 9.0, you may try using `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, like this:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema_1 GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLES TO dev;
```

And I believe only *superuser or owner* has the permission to `DROP`.

You can read more about `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)